# Segmentation fault while reading file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My file looks like:

```
123456789
```

My code gives me segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *f; 
    char ch[5];
    f = open("a.txt", "r");
    fgets( ch, 4, f); 
    ch[4] = NULL;
    printf("%s", ch); //Fixed
    return 0;
}
```

I am an absolute beginner. What am I doing wrong. My aim is to read first 4 characters of the file using `fgets`.

Comment: `open` returns a file descriptor but not a `FILE*`. use `fopen` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do

```
    printf("%s", ch);
```

For the `%` format, the argument is a pointer to characters; by passing a single character by value, you're telling `printf` to interpret that character's ASCII value as a pointer, and that's going to blow up on you; i.e., if the character is a `1`, which is ASCII 49, then it's going to look at byte 49 in memory for a string -- and looking down there is generally *verboten*.

But secondly, I see you're calling `open()` instead of `fopen()`. You must use `fopen()` or you won't get a `FILE*` as you're expecting.

Both of these individually would likely cause a segfault -- you'll need to fix them both.

Comment: Looks like I have to wait 5 minutes to accept the answer. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

try to use "fopen" instead just "open"

Thanks.

Comment: Right, or the opposite solution : using `int fd` instead of `FILE *f`.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of quick changes.

1. I think you want to use fopen rather than open here, since you used a file pointer.
2. You need to increase the bytes read to 5, the last one is terminated by a null by fgets.

   ```
    int main() {

        FILE *f; 
        char ch[5];
        f = fopen("a.txt", "r");
        fgets( ch, 5, f); 
        printf("%s", ch);
        return 0;

    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *f; 
    char ch[5];
    f = fopen("a.txt", "r"); //use fopen
    fgets( ch, 4, f); 
    ch[4] = NULL;
    printf("%s", ch); // modification here pass the address of an array to printf
    return 0;
}
```

try following example from the refereed site

```
/* fgets example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   char mystring [5];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
   if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else {
     if ( fgets (mystring , 5 , pFile) != NULL )
       puts (mystring);
     fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/

you can also use

[fgetc()  :Get character from stream (function)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/)